# How to avoid ai hands or any body part going inside wall or ground? (Unreal Engine4)

Tags: physics, mesh

Whenever my character get killed near wall his hands or any body part its goes through the wall making it look like half of the hands front of wall and another half through back. but i dont like it.. i want it look like modern game where if i killed him near wall it should be realistic where his body part should change posistion according to it. like lifiting his hand because he cant put his hands through wall and also i made a little mistake in my death animation making the hands below the ground so whenever he get killed his hands go through ground.. so how to make this work?

Comment: You'll need to look into implementing rag-doll physics for your character models with collision on them like any other object. I haven't actually implemented it myself so can't give much insight but there are a lot of good tutorials for rag-doll physics

Comment: But someone told me to add inverse kinamatics but your telling me to add ragdoll so confusing but thanks for reply

Comment: Just had a quick look and inverse kinamatics is a way of implementing rag doll physics :) its a specific way to do the general term rag doll, hopefully that makes more sense now!! From what you say it looks like you can already move the hands etc so maybe just add collision detection to all the points on the model (ie hands, elbows, feet knees head) would be the easiest way to stop them clipping through walls but again im not sure whether this is a "good" solution to this!